# How to prove the definite integral for even functions

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with the following proof:

If f is an even function on [−a, a] then $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx$ = $ 2 \int_{a}^{0}f(x)dx$

$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx$

= $\int_{-a}^{0}f(x)dx$ + $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

= $\int_{-a}^{0}f(-x)dx$ + $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

Let u = -x du = -dx
dx = -du

= $-\int_{-a}^{0}f(u)du$ + $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

= $\int_{0}^{-a}f(u)du$ + $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

I get stuck after this step. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You got stuck because, in the step *before* that, you did not change the bounds of integration when you did the $u$-substitution. Namely, when $x$ is $-a$, $u$ is $a$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-a}^{0}f(-x)dx=-\int_{a}^{0}f(u)du=\int_{0}^{a}f(u)du=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you change the bounds of integration?

Comment: For $u=-x$, when $x=-a$, then $u=-(-a)=a$, when $x=0$, then $u=-0=0$.

Comment: so x = -a is when the integration limit occurs at -a?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: So the substitution has to occur at the integration limits and the function as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to change them all together.

Comment: wait so if u = -x then how does $\int_{0}^{a}f(u)du$ = $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$ then?

Comment: That has nothing to do with $u=-x$. For the variable $u$ in $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}f(u)du$ is dummy, you can change to write $x$ or $y$ or $z$, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm still kinda confused

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}f(u)du=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}f(y)dy=\cdots$ there is no role for $u,x,y,...$ inside the integral.

Comment: Why is there no role? I'm just kinda confused about the dummy variable thing

Comment: For example $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}2xdx=1$, then can you see as well that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}2udu=1$ and also that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}2ydy=1$?

Comment: @deezy $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$, $v$, etc. are just names for variables.  They have no intrinsic meaning.  The integrals $\int_{a}^{b} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u$ and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ are exactly the same thing.  The *names* of the variables don't matter, just the role that they play in the argument.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now, thanks.